# JPA How to retrieve values from another table?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, eclipselink

Suppose I have 2 tables A and B.

```
Table A:   id, code1, code2, code3, code4   (id is the primary key)
Table B:   codeID, displayText, someOtherColumn  (codeID is the primary key)
```

code1,code2, code3 and code4 are just CodeIDs from Table B

Now I have class

```
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;


    //Now How To Get the displayText based on codeID in Table B?
    private String code1Display;
    private String code2Display;
    private String code3Display;
    private String code3Display

}
```

I thought I should use "SecondaryTable" annotation. But from reading Chris' reply here, this is not going to work. So how should I achieve my goal here?

I just need to read the those values, not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappings for attributes code1Display, code2Display etc will default to using fields "CODE1DISPALY", "CODE2DISPLAY", etc on the main table A if column info isn't specified.  So for each attribute mapping you will need to specify tha table the field exists on:

```
@Column(name = "CODE1", table = "B")
private String code1Display;
```

The secondary table annotation is for specifying the second table and how it is linked to the main table.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/SecondaryTable. But in your case it is simply:

@SecondaryTable(name = "B", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="codeID"))

Comment: This would be the answer if what you wanted was actually a secondary table, but looking again, it won't work.  Secondary tables are used when each row in the second table corresponds to a strict 1:1 in the main - neither can exist without the other.  You seem to have many rows in B for each row in A.  B should be its own entity.

Comment: So there's no annotation can achieve my goal here? If I make B an entity,how do I get my "code1Display" value in the code above? Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't.  You would instead have a reference to entity B, which would contain a field 'displayText'.  Your Foo entity could have an accessor method, getCode1Display() that simply returned code1.displayText if you wanted to abstract it from the application.